# Having trouble rendering the HTML5 Slider vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile to render a Slider and it works great.  However, I am having trouble getting it to show up vertically.  The specs say (at least my reading of them) that the slider figures out whether to show up vertically or horizontally based on the height/width, but it's not working in my case.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <title>jQuery Mobile Docs - Forms</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />  

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script> 

        <style type="text/css">
            #wheel1Speed { height: 300px; width: 100px;}    
        </style>        

    </head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">  
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <input type="range" name="wheel1speed" id="wheel1speed" 
            value="0" min="-100" max="100" data-theme="b" data-track-theme="a"  /> 
    </div><!-- /content --> 
</div><!-- /page --> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: That appears to be the spec, but, at least in Safari, sliders don't work vertically. Some browsers may not have implemented that yet?

Comment: @ddargadi I am able to make the vertical slider work in Chrome as implemented at http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/rangeinput/vertical.html.  However, the jQuery Mobile sliders actually work on the iPhone, e.g. dragging the thumb does not drag the entire page, where as the one at the link does.

Comment: "wheel1Speed" != "wheel1speed"

Comment: @naugtur Good catch, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: One more thing - when you posted the question JQM alpha3 was already out. Please try that, because you might have read its docs, and you are linking JQMa2 to the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked through JQM documentation (latest) and found no info about a slider being able to display vertically

I also found this:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/is-there-a-vertical-slider-for-jquery-mobile

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but the guy provides no solution whatsoever.  In fact, the last comment is mine.

Comment: he said it's easy to fix it to display vertically. You probably have to change some css and swap some x and y

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to force the slider in vertical mode for Webkit browsers (Chrome & Safari):

```
#wheel1speed {
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this approach which I like:

```
#wheel1speed {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```